# Websocket Handshake - cookie can't be parsed?

Tags: java, cookies, websocket

In Spring I set some cookies I need for my websocket:

```
 Cookie ck = new Cookie("session", request.getSession().getId());
        ck.setDomain(".mydomain.com");
        ck.setPath("/");
        ck.setVersion(1);
 Cookie secretCookie = new Cookie("scrt", secret);
        secretCookie.setDomain(".mydomain.com");
        secretCookie.setPath("/");
        secretCookie.setVersion(1);
        response.addCookie(secretCookie);
        response.addCookie(ck);
```

But when I read the header of the websocket handshake, the value of the cookie field only consists of a string which looks like this:

```
session=foobar; scrt=foomart
```

When you try to parse this value by `HttpCookie.parse();` the HTTPCookie will try to identify the version of the cookie.

```
private static int guessCookieVersion(String header) {
    int version = 0;

    header = header.toLowerCase();
    if (header.indexOf("expires=") != -1) {
        // only netscape cookie using 'expires'
        version = 0;
    } else if (header.indexOf("version=") != -1) {
        // version is mandatory for rfc 2965/2109 cookie
        version = 1;
    } else if (header.indexOf("max-age") != -1) {
        // rfc 2965/2109 use 'max-age'
        version = 1;
    } else if (startsWithIgnoreCase(header, SET_COOKIE2)) {
        // only rfc 2965 cookie starts with 'set-cookie2'
        version = 1;
    }

    return version;
}
```

If the Value is 0, which is wrong but the case here, the HttpCookie will only parse the first entry. 
If you force version to be 1, this won't work either, since HttpCookie is expecting comma seperated values.  `splitMultiCookies(String header)`

Is there any way to fix this but writing my own parser?

Answer (score 0):

It is funny because a cookie has no field "version" anymore. I can find a reference to it in the [RFC2109 (1997)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109), but it is not there anymore in [RFC6265 (2011)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2). Actually, the cookie API in .NET does not provide a built-in method to set such property (that is the reason this caught my attention). Check that the browser is actually sending that data as part of the handshake, maybe the browser is ignoring it.

Comment: Yes, the cookie header only contains `session=foobar; scrt=foomart`. But then HttpCookie.parse() doesn't work correct, does it?

Comment: I don't know how java handles it, the case is that "version" is not part of the specification anymore. Are you sure you are using the right java version?

Comment: What do you mean by "right java version"? I'm running  1.7.0_17.